# How we can read application.yml with websocket configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I am creating a spring application which uses @EnableWebSocket annotation on my main class. I also have application.yml file on classpath which has some configuration for Eureka and other client connect. When I am running the server application.yml is not getting loaded but if i comment out @EnableWebSocket annotation from my main class yml file starts loading, but then my server will no longer support ws/wss protocol.

How can I read application.yml along with @EnableWebSocket annotation.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "application.yml is not getting loaded"?

Comment: I have to read some values from application.yml like the name , url etc from it . with @Value annotation value is still null . Also I have Eureka server configuration in application.yml but that also dosen't work. If I remove any placeholder from application.yml then also server gets started without throwing any error as server is not loading application.yml on startup.